# openssl error "error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading" while using SSL_accept(...)

Tags: c++, server, openssl

So currently, I am writing my own web server which is using the openssl library (most recent version from 2022/07/05).

While initializing the openssl library I specify TLS 1.3 as the minimum version with `SSL_CTX_set_min_proto_version( sslctx, TLS1_3_VERSION );`

The client accept logic, simplified, looks the following:

- SSL_new()
- SSL_set_fd()
- SSL_accept()
- Error checking with the SSL_accept() return value
- SSL_read()
- SSL_write()
- SSL_shutdown()
- SSL_free()
- close()

Everything works fine so far, I can locally connect with my Firefox-browser (102.0 - 64 bit and Kubuntu 22.04 - 64 bit).

The problem now begins, when I press and keep pressing the F5 key to spam refresh for the current page/resource.
When I am doing that, the error check catches the following error:
`error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading`.

The openssl docu for the [SSL_shutdown](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/SSL_shutdown.html) function states that there are implementations that do not send the required close_notify alert and therefore the error can be suppressed by adding `SSL_OP_IGNORE_UNEXPECTED_EOF` as a flag when setting the flags with `SSL_CTX_set_options()` during initialization.
Even though, I don't think Firefox is not sending the close_notify, but I guess just not in case after sending x amount of requests?

Is it safe to suppress that error message or do I miss something else which I need to implement to catch when someone is spamming refresh button?